# How can I stay focused and enjoy work when I am the only member on a team?

Tags: work-environment, communication, relationships

I am working solely on a project since few weeks, and there is no one currently in my team.
I don't have any problems regards to work, and i have no competition or challenge too. I directly communicate with my client remotely.

There are more than 2 people in all other teams, working collectively and co-operating with each other. I am not feeling jealous anyways, though I miss the joy of sharing my work with other members. I feel sometimes lonely and being abandoned.

My question is, how to effectively deal with other people in this situation, and get the boredom off from my work place. I also lack enough motivation and recognition. To overcome this, i often read good quotes online, but again, that's a waste of time and carries a bad impression with other people (Some feel that i am not at all working and just enjoying, while my Client is happy with my work). I don't prefer to spend time in Cafeteria either, as it makes me deviate from the work mood.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> though I miss the joy of sharing my work with other members. I feel sometimes lonely and being abandoned.

Problem.

> I don't prefer to spend time in Cafeteria either, as it makes me deviate from the work mood.

So you don't want to interact with people in normal social interactions (like lunch) because you don't like not being in the "work mood" but want to interact with others? This seems like you are saying, "I know an easy solution to my problem but don't want to do it." Woe is me, people at my workplace who don't work on my project and I avoid all interactions with don't seek me out and come find me.

There is an easy solution here - talk with those on other teams in the most normal interactions ever, lunch. Make an effort to sit with random people every day, you'll be surprised how much you can learn. Try to be interested in who they are and ask about what they are doing and you will start seeing. People generally react well to others taking interest in their life/work/etc and eventually will ask YOU about YOUR life.

If you want to value work above all social interactions then don't be surprised if you feel isolated or lonely. That's... going to happen.

Comment: >Make an effort to sit with random people every day. This is very culture/geography/race dependent. You do that in my neck of the woods and people put one hand on their holster (while eat with the other)

Answer (score 2):

I work alone out of my apartment, remoting in to clients as needed.  Most of the time I can do my work without remote access - I have everything I need on my own machine. I meet people for lunch, and I get on SO, LinkedIn, and a few other sites every hour or so to read up and to make comments. This keeps me from being a hermit.

Get to know real people in your work and in relation to personal interests.  If there are people that work on either 'similar projects' or ones you're interested in, see if you can chat with them from time to time. It breaks up what is otherwise pretty monotonous.